# Calling an overridable method in constructor

Tags: java, interface

I have multiple different implementations of an object, which implement this custom `interface` I made called `Board`.

`Board` contains a method that looks like the following

```
public void ConvertFromString(String formattedString);
```

Each object implementing `Board` calls `ConvertFromString()` in its constructor.

Looks like the following.

```
public void BoardImpl1 implements Board
{
    public Board(string B)
    {
        ConvertFromString(b);
    }

    public void ConvertFromString(String formattedString)
    {
        //do some parsing on string and set up the BoardImpl properties
    }
}
```

ConvertFromString being public causes a warning, so one of the workarounds that I found would be to make `BoardImpl` final. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: You have a class called `BoardImpl1`, why don't you make `Board` an abstract class instead of an interface?

Comment: Im looking into seeing if I can rearcthitect that. the problem is that `BoardImpl1` extends an unrelated abstract class already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> //do some parsing on string and set up the BoardImpl properties

The method should be responsible to convertFromString only.

1) Make the method final

```
public class BoardImpl implements Board{

  public void final convertFromString(String formattedString)
  {
        //do some parsing on string and set up the BoardImpl properties
  }

}
```

2) Solution make an `abstract class` and call in superClass constructor so you don't have to call in each subclass **BUT don't use properties from subclass cause they aren't intilized**.

```
public abstract class AbstractBoard implements Board{

     public AbstractBoard(String s){
       convertFromString(s);
     }

}
```

3) And My preferred one make something with composition

```
public class Client {

 private Board board;

  public Client(String s){
   board.convertFromString(s);
  }

 public void setBoard(Board board){
      this.board = board;
 } 

}
```

Then in the board you can delegate responsability of deciding wich Board you should use to a factory or if it has no state a `FlyweightFactory`

Comment: I like the idea of number 3. Im looking into creating a factory which will return me a `BoardImpl` and call the `convertFromString` method. The problem with an abstract class is that it doesn't guarantee that `convertFromString` will be defined, and I need a separate definition for each implementation of the `Board` interface

Comment: @Rhs yeah the 3rd is the better and if you mix with a Factory better, you can use a `Flyweight` if the `strategies classes` don't have internal state

Answer (score 1):

Does `ConvertFromString` really belong in the `Board` interface to begin with? What if you had a board that initialized its properties a different way? I would consider refactoring out the board class if you can.

```
public class Board {
   public Board(Properties properties) {...}
}
```

I think the reason you're having trouble setting this up without calling the public `ConvertFromString` method is because the design is a little off. The `ConvertFromString` makes assumptions about the implementation of it.

Comment: `convertFromString` comes from an interface so I can't mark the function protected or private.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is compile error in your code
2. I could not get a compile warning with following code

   ```
   public interface Board {

     public void ConvertFromString(String formattedString);

   }


   public class BoardImpl1 implements Board {

     public BoardImpl1(String b) {

       ConvertFromString(b);

     }

     public void ConvertFromString(String formattedString) {

       //bla bla

     }

   }
   ```

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: @MrD You're correct... But unfortunately, I could not comment on other's post before 50 reputation... So I will remove this "answer" after Rhs read it, or is there other way to notify him that his code has compile error? Thanks.

Comment: you may considering deleting ; in }; in interface